# How to set route for "home" in Angular 2 app-routing.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I'm looking at some basic "introduction to Angular" tutorials and have an unresolved question about setting route paths. While it is clear how to define a path to a component and navigate to that component, I do not see an example of how to set a route to the "home" page.

I can see how the other routes work, because they point to components that I created. So if I click a "manage" link, I see the correct URL: "http://localhost:4200/manage".

My question, is how I set up a route so that when I click "home" the URL is shown: "http://localhost:4200/".

I should mention that this -- for now -- a skeleton project generated by CLI.

```
ng new my-app --routing
ng generate component tools
ng generate component reports
ng generate component manage
```

Once the project was generated, I then added these routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  /*
  * How do I create a path for the "home" page?

  { path: 'home', component: ?? },
  */
  { path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent },
  { path: 'tools', component: ToolsComponent },
  { path: 'manage', component: ManageComponent }
];
```

Comment: `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }`

Comment: @JBNizet -- I don't have a home component.

Comment: Well, define one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question. I have no defined "home" route or default route.

Instead, on the HTML side I manually point to the root with my "Home" link.

```
<nav>
  <ul>    
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['/reports']">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['/tools']">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['/manage']">Manage</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```